# Calculated column with IF(AND(OR statement to derive a value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I would like to use an `IF(OR(AND` function (or a function that works) to obtain an answer of 1 or -100 within a SharePoint list. My formula works in Excel but not in SharePoint.

```
=IF(OR(AND(Q10="NO",P10<=0.1),AND(Q10="YES",P10<=0.2)),1,-100)
```

Discount = 0.2
LVR<70% = yes
(RESULT WILL EQUAL 1)

If LVR is <70%, then the maximum discount can be up to 0.2 (ranging in value from 0.01 through to 0.2 with intervals of 0.01)

Discount = 0.1
LVR<70% = no
(RESULT WILL EQUAL -100)

If LVR is NOT <70%, then the maximum discount can be up to 0.1 (ranging in value from 0.01 through to 0.1 with intervals of 0.01)
This works in excel.

When I move it over to the calculated column in SharePoint:

```
=IF(OR(AND([LVR<70%]="NO",[Proposed % discount]<=0.1),AND([LVR<70%]="YES",[Proposed % discount]<=0.2)),1,-100)
```

SharePoint accepts it but doesn't calculate the correct answer. (always gives -100 as the answer).

The calculated column is "The data type returned from this formula is: Single line of text".

Comment: What is the data type and other settings of `[Proposed % discount]` column? Can you please attach the screenshot of "column settings" for this column (if possible)? This will help us to understand how data is stored in `[Proposed % discount]`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen very bad things happening when special characters are involved in a column name. Using `<` and `%` in a column name is a really bad idea.

But that's not the cause of your issue. You never mention the data type of the column `[LVR<70%]` but since you test against "YES" and "NO" I assume it's a Yes/No field.

While SharePoint displays the values as yes and no, internally they are stored as Boolean TRUE/FALSE values. So, in order to evaluate them, you only need the field name. It returns either TRUE or FALSE.

[image]

So, you need to rework you formula to use the column name as a boolean, like this

```
=IF(OR(AND(not([LVR<70%]),[Proposed % discount]<=0.1),AND([LVR<70%],[Proposed % discount]<=0.2)),1,-100)
```

Finally a screenshot with the more complex formula at work, just using different thresholds:

[image]

edit 2: formula at work with OP's settings

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, however the result is still showing as -100 when the result should be 1.
You are correct that the Yes/No are a Yes/No field.
I have entered data of:
LVR<70% = yes
Proposed discount =0.12
with the answer returning -100, when it should be 1

Comment: Can you post the formula that you are now using? You can see in my screenshot that the approach works, so maybe there's something amiss with your formula.

Comment: I have taken your advice and removed special characters. Formula is:
=IF(OR(AND(NOT([LVR 70]),[Proposed discount]<=0.1),AND([LVR 70],[Proposed discount]<=0.2)),1,-100)

Comment: Check your values in Proposed Discount. I'm using your exact formula and it works fine.

Comment: I added another screenshot where you can see that I'm using your exact formula. If you get different results, then your values for Proposed Discount are not what you are checking for. Using percentages instead of numbers can do that. I gotta go offline now.

Comment: thanks - I have created a brand new list to test your equation and it still doesn't work. 
All variations give -100 as an answer
My new list only has the 3 columns...
LVR 70 Yes/No 
discount rate Choice 
rate test Calculated (calculation based on other columns)

Comment: Is the value 0.1 or is it 1%? Return the value of the discount rate in a calculated column to see how it is stored. You can see from my screenshot that it works if the discount is a number column, not a percentage column.